# What does Rashi mean by the words "לחבר ולפטרון"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, translation, vayigash

In Parshas Vayigash (פרק מה פסוק ח), Yosef tells his brothers to tell Yaakov Avinu that

> וישימני לאב לפרעה

"[G-d] made me a father to Pharaoh". Rashi comments and says that this means

> לחבר ולפטרון

What does Rashi mean by these words?

Comment: It is a bit unclear as to what Rashi means by these words however through my short research I understand him to mean that Pharaoh made Yosef like a friend (חבר) and guardian (פטרון) to Pharaoh. Jastrow defines פטרון as "a protector". Rashi is really just quoting Bereishis Rabbah 93:10.

Comment: Patron And member of council

Comment: @kouty - the word Patron in English has too many meanings: https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fr&text=patron

Comment: Seems that every Perush and Targum has a variant on this theme. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.45.8?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he - no time to write it up - feel free to do so, anybody.

Comment: @DannySchoemann yes I just wanted to make a transliteration.